# pytubeのライブラリーから出てくるクラス変数から値を取り出したい。

Tags: python, python3

pytubeのライブラリーを使用しているのですが以下のコードでクラス変数から値を取り出そうと考えたのですが、全部`None`になりうまく取り出せません。

```
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2">
```

クラスの中のデータは上記のようになっています。

```
from pytube import YouTube
# from enum import Enum

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3cYmuXUbl0'

class Youtubehq():
    """docstring for Youtubehq"""
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def movieq(self):
        yt = YouTube(self.url)
        for class_d in yt.streams.all():
            res = class_d.res
            print(res)


selectq = Youtubehq(url)
selectq.movieq()
```

詳しい方ご教授して頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resはresolutionの略なので、`class_d.resolution`を試してください。
(実装でもresと略しています: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/streams.py#L314

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事取り出せました。しかしなぜ省略してあるとその省略形で取り出せないのでしょうか？これは別の質問になるのでスレッドを立てた方が良いですよね。

Comment: 省略形は画面表示時のみで実際の変数としては定義されていないからです。